# Sentence ending with こと or もの in mathematics definitions

Tags: nominalization, mathematics

I'm reading a mathematics textbook, and there are a number of sentences which end with もの or こと.

I can work out the intended meaning no problem, so what I would like explained to me, are the rules for when I can use this grammatical construction.

This seems to happen in definitions, especially if mathematically written conditions are involved.

For example:

> すなわち
>
> 1. m1, m2 ∈ N ⇒ m1 + m2 ∈ N,　さらに 0 ∈ N
> 2. r ∈ R, n ∈ N ⇒ r•n ∈ N
>
> となるもの。

or

> f: S → T 全射 (surjection, epimorphism) であるとは、f (S) = T が成立すること。

I asked a (non-Japanese) mathematician, who told me that this can be used to give commands, e.g., 勉強すること。However, I don't see why a command would appear in definitions in this way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence-final copula `である` ("be") is almost always omitted because it's obvious in definitions, leaving the sentences looking like ending with nouns. Both `もの` and `こと` are frequently used nominalizers translating "what do ~" and "doing ~" respectively.

> すなわち、1. (...) 2. (...) となるもの。
>   *i.e. **what** satisfies 1. (...) and 2. (...).*

---

> f:S→T が全射であるとは、f(S)=T が成立すること。
>   *f:S→T is a surjection means **that** f(S)=T holds true.*
>   less literally, *f:S→T is a surjection when f(S)=T holds true.*

Answer (score -1):

I looked up "成立" and two of the meanings are "coming into existence; conclusion" while having the meaning "to hold true" as a suru verb. I think "成立すること" is simply to address the multiple meanings of the word, and it also refers to the noun (f(S)=T) possessing the quality of the verb (成立する) by nominalizing the verb (こと).

I haven't read a math book in a while, but if I can still remember mathematicians parlance (haha) I would translate it as: "When f:S→T is a surjection, f(S)=T still holds true."

Comment: I should have maybe given more context. The examples come from definitions. I would translate the second one as: "A morphism f:S→T is an epimorphism if f(S)=T holds true." Its from the definition of an epismorphism.